# Bitbucket Pipeline Python Deployment failing all of a sudden

Tags: python, bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines

I have been trying to solve this for a few days and not sure what the issue could be, for my deployments we use bitbucket pipelines and have been able to deploy without any issue, and now today when I went to do a deploy it all of a sudden failed.

And the only change that I made in this commit was updating an error text. So just not sure as to why this would start happening all of a sudden.

It seems like it always keep failing on the `pipenv install --skip-lock --system` step.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5HQGk.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FeNn5.jpg)

```
options:
  docker: true
image: python:3.8-slim


test: &test
  step:
    name: 'Build and Test'
    script:
      - echo "Your build and test goes here..."
lint: &lint
  step:
    name: 'Lint'
    script:
      - echo "Your linting goes here..."
      -


push-development: &push-development
  step:
    name: 'Deployment to Partners'
    deployment: partners
    image: google/cloud-sdk:latest
    caches:
      - docker
    trigger: 'manual'
    script:
      - echo ${KEY_FILE_AUTH} | base64 --decode --ignore-garbage > /tmp/gcloud-api.json
      - echo ${ENV_FILE} | base64 --decode --ignore-garbage > ./api/settings/.env
      - pip install pip pipenv --upgrade
      - pipenv install --skip-lock --system
      - pip install -r ./requirements.txt
      - source ./api/settings/.env
```

```
42s
+ pipenv install --skip-lock --system
Installing dependencies from Pipfile...
An error occurred while installing protobuf==3.15.2! Will try again.
An error occurred while installing pyasn1==0.4.8! Will try again.
An error occurred while installing pyasn1-modules==0.2.8! Will try again.
An error occurred while installing pycparser==2.20! Will try again.
An error occurred while installing pydotplus==2.0.2! Will try again.
An error occurred while installing pyparsing==2.4.7! Will try again.
An error occurred while installing python-http-client==3.3.1! Will try again.
An error occurred while installing pytz==2021.1! Will try again.
An error occurred while installing requests==2.25.1! Will try again.
An error occurred while installing requests-file==1.5.1! Will try again.
An error occurred while installing requests-oauthlib==1.3.0! Will try again.
An error occurred while installing requests-toolbelt==0.9.1! Will try again.
An error occurred while installing rsa==4.7.2! Will try again.
An error occurred while installing scipy==1.6.1! Will try again.
An error occurred while installing sendgrid==6.5.0! Will try again.
An error occurred while installing sentry-sdk==0.16.5! Will try again.
An error occurred while installing singledispatch==3.6.0! Will try again.
An error occurred while installing six==1.15.0! Will try again.
An error occurred while installing sqlparse==0.4.1! Will try again.
An error occurred while installing starkbank-ecdsa==1.1.0! Will try again.
An error occurred while installing text-unidecode==1.3! Will try again.
An error occurred while installing uritemplate==3.0.1! Will try again.
An error occurred while installing urllib3==1.26.3! Will try again.
An error occurred while installing virtualenv==20.0.30! Will try again.
An error occurred while installing virtualenv-clone==0.5.4! Will try again.
An error occurred while installing zeep==4.0.0! Will try again.
An error occurred while installing django==3.1.6! Will try again.
An error occurred while installing pyjwt==1.7.1! Will try again.
An error occurred while installing pillow==7.2.0! Will try again.
An error occurred while installing rx==1.6.1! Will try again.
An error occurred while installing unidecode==1.1.1! Will try again.
An error occurred while installing django-rest-framework! Will try again.
An error occurred while installing requests-futures! Will try again.
An error occurred while installing django-constance! Will try again.
An error occurred while installing django-picklefield! Will try again.
An error occurred while installing django-environ! Will try again.
An error occurred while installing dj-database-url! Will try again.
Installing initially failed dependencies...
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]: /usr/bin/python3: can't open file '/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pipenv/patched/pip': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
ERROR: Couldn't install package: protobuf
 Package installation failed...
/usr/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py:858: ResourceWarning: subprocess 465 is still running
  ResourceWarning, source=self)
ResourceWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback
sys:1: ResourceWarning: unclosed file <_io.FileIO name=4 mode='rb' closefd=True>
ResourceWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback
sys:1: ResourceWarning: unclosed file <_io.FileIO name=7 mode='rb' closefd=True>
ResourceWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback
/usr/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py:858: ResourceWarning: subprocess 466 is still running
  ResourceWarning, source=self)
ResourceWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback
sys:1: ResourceWarning: unclosed file <_io.FileIO name=6 mode='rb' closefd=True>
ResourceWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback
sys:1: ResourceWarning: unclosed file <_io.FileIO name=9 mode='rb' closefd=True>
ResourceWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback
/usr/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py:858: ResourceWarning: subprocess 467 is still running
  ResourceWarning, source=self)
ResourceWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback
sys:1: ResourceWarning: unclosed file <_io.FileIO name=8 mode='rb' closefd=True>
ResourceWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback
sys:1: ResourceWarning: unclosed file <_io.FileIO name=11 mode='rb' closefd=True>
ResourceWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback
/usr/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py:858: ResourceWarning: subprocess 468 is still running
  ResourceWarning, source=self)
ResourceWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback
sys:1: ResourceWarning: unclosed file <_io.FileIO name=10 mode='rb' closefd=True>
ResourceWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback
sys:1: ResourceWarning: unclosed file <_io.FileIO name=13 mode='rb' closefd=True>
ResourceWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback
/usr/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py:858: ResourceWarning: subprocess 469 is still running
  ResourceWarning, source=self)
ResourceWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback
sys:1: ResourceWarning: unclosed file <_io.FileIO name=12 mode='rb' closefd=True>
ResourceWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback
sys:1: ResourceWarning: unclosed file <_io.FileIO name=15 mode='rb' closefd=True>
ResourceWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback
/usr/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py:858: ResourceWarning: subprocess 470 is still running
  ResourceWarning, source=self)
ResourceWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback
sys:1: ResourceWarning: unclosed file <_io.FileIO name=14 mode='rb' closefd=True>
ResourceWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback
sys:1: ResourceWarning: unclosed file <_io.FileIO name=17 mode='rb' closefd=True>
ResourceWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback
```

Comment: This could be related to the recent rush in pipenv releases? I would try to freeze pipenv to the version of your last successful build and try to reproduce the issue locally. Also, adding a `--verbose` option to the failing pipenv instruction could give you useful information about the root of those errors.